# How to properly add an object to an array? (Processing 3.5.4)

Tags: java, arrays, object, append

Currently I have:

```
nameHere[] array;
void setup() {
 array = new nameHere[60];
}

void draw() {
 //statements go here
}

class nameHere {
 int nameA, nameB, nameC;
 nameHere (int a, int b, int c) {
  nameA = a;
  nameB = b;
  nameC = c;
 }
 void functionHere() {
  //statements go here
 }
}

void mousePressed() {
 array.append(nameHere(0, 0, 0));
}
```

As far as I can tell, all of my syntaxes are correct. The console's returned error is "function nameHere(int, int, int) does not exist." May someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is, as you said, in the line

```
array.append(nameHere(0, 0, 0))
```

You are missing the keyword **new** before **nameHere(0, 0, 0)** this leads to the compiler thinking you want to call a function which doesn't exist. By adding the keyword you are telling the compiler that instead should create an instance of the class **nameHere**.

Unfortunately I am not able to test the solution, but hope it helps!